# Best way to round off the edges in a rectangle

Tags: bevel

I'm trying to model an indoor football field which is like a hockey rink...

I've been able to add the bevel modifier; but, I've read where there is a better way to accomplish this.  Can someone walk me through the steps and help me apply 20 to 32 segments...

I've created the rectangle and placed it in edit mode; but, I'm getting confused as to how to add the bevel to the corners and then knock out the middle of the rectangle for the raised border walls..

Thanks
Trey

Comment: can you add some reference images what your looking for

Comment: see this link for an image of a hockey rink model...  https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1&biw=1600&bih=758&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=xUZ5Wr_VIOO4jwTv4Y6YCg&q=blender+hockey+rink+models&oq=blender+hockey+rink+models&gs_l=psy-ab.3...22154.23678.0.23920.7.7.0.0.0.0.80.543.7.7.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.drCR7uKIae4#imgdii=WKjSAjCTFmOtWM:&imgrc=HS4q9OeqVi2HXM:

Comment: Select your verts and press ctrl+shift+B, this will bevel your corners. You can scroll to increase or decrease the divisions. Afterwards us an inset (select face -> I) and drag to create your inner area.

Answer (score 1):

If i understood the question

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> Add Plane

Go to edit mode and make the shape rectangular

Come out of the edit mode and Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> Apply rotation & scale

Go to edit mode with the verts selected Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> Bevel it and scroll to add segments

With the rectangular rounded shape selected. Press <kbd>I</kbd> to offset the face

Now select the edge and extrude it and delete the top face. Select the bottom edge and Press <kbd>F</kbd> to fill the face

[image]

Comment: Your last action (filling the face) results in non manifold geometry.

Comment: None of that works for me--- I see no vertices when I go to edit mode...  what am I missing...Ive tried holding down control-shift-b all at the same and then one after another and it does nothing.----totally confused as to what I'm doing wrong here...why add a plane--why wouldn't I just add a rectangle and size it right off the bat...

Comment: I was finally able to get the bevel and vertices applied-- is their a simpler way rather than holding down 3 keys and going to the edit mode...

Comment: ok once again after much trial and error i was able to get it to look like yours... how do i go about adding some width to the walls around the rectangle....

Comment: you mean adding thickness to the walls. If so just add solidify modifier